# addClass & removeClass Transitions - Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

**EDIT:** Resolved the text issue, still need help with the Firefox transition.

Trying to use a minimal menu once you scroll down the page. The code works in the sense that it is transitioning, however it is not transitioning as I would like it to. There are two problems:

1. <strike>In Chrome the text "slides" to the middle only after everything else has moved.</strike>
2. In Firefox, the image doesn't transition/fade, it just simply "opens up" from the right.

In an ideal situation I want the image to animate like it does in Chrome, but I want the text to slide into position like it does in Firefox.

I have looked up other questions on Stackoverflow and elsewhere, but none seem to have a solution for the differences between Webkit & Moz.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8pFWj/1/) of the problem.

Try this:

```js
$(document).on("scroll",function(){
        if($(document).scrollTop()>100){ 
            $(".logo").removeClass("logo_large").addClass("logo_small");
            $("header").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
            }
        else{
            $(".logo").removeClass("logo_small").addClass("logo_large");
            $("header").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
            }
        });
```

```css
.small li, .large li, .logo_large, .logo_small {
    transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 1s; /* Opera */
}

nav {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
    display:inline-table;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display:table-cell;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.large li {
    height: 120px;
    line-height: 120px;
}

.small li {
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
}

.logo_large {
    height: 130px;
    width: 164px;
    background:url(https://unsplash.it/200/300) no-repeat;
}

.logo_small {
    height: 80px;
    width: 50px;
    background:url(https://unsplash.it/200/300) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="large">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="logo logo_large"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the transitions from `header, a, img, li{...` and add to the actual elements:

```
.large li {
    height: 120px;
    line-height: 120px;
    transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 1s; /* Opera */
}

.small li {
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 1s; /* Opera */
}

.logo_large {
    height: 130px;
    width: 164px;
    background:url(http://samaradionne.com/img/typeBlack.png) no-repeat;
    transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 1s; /* Opera */
}

.logo_small {
    height: 80px;
    width: 50px;
    background:url(http://samaradionne.com/img/logoBlack.png) no-repeat;
    transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 1s; /* Opera */
}
```

Comment: Upvoting because it fixed the Chrome issue (text is transitioning properly) however it didn't fix the Firefox one. :(

Answer (score 1):

If those are your only two states, you might avoid the problem by creating a persistent class and an overlay class, and applying your styles to these, e.g.:

```
.logo { }
.logo.minimized { }
```

Simply add and remove the overlay style.

This should allow jQuery to properly calculate the transition.